# Coffeescript in Jsfiddle Uncaught SyntaxError

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript, jsfiddle

I'm having the following error in jsfiddle using backbone, underscore and coffeescript: http://jsfiddle.net/bx7g7d2y/3/

It seems my code is OK, the error raises in coffeescript file, line 8.

This is my demo code:

```
# extending a simple model
SidebarModel = Backbone.Model.extend {
    initialize: -> {
        console.log 'initialized'
    }
}

sidebar = new SidebarModel
```

Can you spot something that I'd missing ?

**UPDATE:**
By the other hand, it works neat with javascript:

```
// extending a simple model
var SidebarModel = Backbone.Model.extend ({
    initialize: function(){
        console.log('initialized');
    }
})

var sidebar = new SidebarModel();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following in the `Try CoffeScript`-tab on the [CoffeScript](http://coffeescript.org/) website.

```
SidebarModel = Backbone.Model.extend {
    initialize: -> 
        console.log 'initialized'
}

sidebar = new SidebarModel
```

`->` is the [CoffeScript-literal](http://coffeescript.org/#literals) for a function. No brackets needed for that!

You could even go one step further and write:

```
SidebarModel = Backbone.Model.extend 
    initialize: -> 
        console.log 'initialized'

sidebar = new SidebarModel
```

Comment: it worked, now my question is: why ? isn't supposed that I can embed a function body within curly brackets ?

Comment: @alexserver Updated the answer :)

Comment: @alexserver No you don't wrap function bodies in braces in CoffeeScript. You should also use `class SidebarModel extends Backbone.Model` since CoffeeScript's `class ... extends` mechanism is compatible with Backbone's `extends`.